# How to write a custom tag to read and print arraylist?

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist

I am new to jsp custom tags. What I wanted is print ArrayList in my jsp page by using a custom tag.

My custom tag's .tld file is below,

```
<tag>
    <name>HotelDetails</name>
    <tag-class>it.testproject.custom.HotelDetails</tag-class>
    <body-content>JSP</body-content>
    <attribute>
        <name>id</name>
        <required>true</required>
        <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        <type>java.lang.String</type>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <name>hotelArray</name>
        <required>true</required>
        <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        <type>java.util.ArrayList</type>
    </attribute>
</tag>
```

Here I have used attribute to get arraylist. and I can access it in the jsp page.

My tag handler class is looks like,

```
package it.testproject.custom;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.servlet.jsp.JspException;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.BodyTagSupport;

public class HotelDetails extends BodyTagSupport
{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1141701851233089895L;
private Hotel hotel;
private ArrayList<Hotel> hotelArray;
City regionCity;
Iterator<Hotel> it;


public ArrayList<Hotel> getHotelArray()
{
    return hotelArray;
}

public void setHotelArray( ArrayList<Hotel> hotelArray )
{
    this.hotelArray = hotelArray;
    it=hotelArray.iterator();
    System.out.println( "[HotelDetails]  Hotels : " + hotelArray.size() );
}

@Override
public int doStartTag() throws JspException
{
    hotel=it.next();

    pageContext.setAttribute( "hotelName", hotel.getName() );
    pageContext.setAttribute( "hotelDesc", hotel.getDescription() );
    pageContext.setAttribute( "hotelRating", hotel.getStarRating() );
    pageContext.setAttribute( "defaultPrice", hotel.getTotalPriceWithTax() );

    System.out.println(hotel.getName()+" "+hotel.getStarRating());

    // pageContext.setAttribute( "hotelDesc", hotel.getDescription() );
    // pageContext.setAttribute( "hotelRating", hotel.getStarRating() );
    // pageContext.setAttribute( "hotelMainImage", hotelImageBase + hotel.getMainImage().getImageURL() );

    return EVAL_BODY_INCLUDE;
}

}
```

I have returned EVAL_BODY_INCLUDE and it gets only one result. I saw in some posts about EVAL_PAGE to call doStartTag() automatically. I tried, but no results. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Simple Tag

A simple tag has the following characteristics:

- Start and End of tag -No body is specified within tag -No attributes

For example

```
<mytag:hello/>
```

#### Tag with Attributes

A tag with attributes has the following characteristics:

- Start and End of tag
- Attributes within tag
- No body enclosed

For example

```
<mytag:hello attribute = "value" />
```

#### Tag with Body

A tag with body has the following characteristics:

- Start and End of tag
- May be attributes
- Body enclosed within tag

For example

```
<mytag:hello optional_attributes ............>
    some body
</mytag:hello>
```

---

Have a look at [Building a Custom Tag Library](http://java.boot.by/wcd-guide/ch10.html) that describe the semantics of the "Classic" custom tag event model when each event method (doStartTag, doAfterBody, and doEndTag) is executed, and explain what the return value for each event method means; and write a tag handler class.

#### Tag Handler Methods

[image]

#### Tag Lifecycle

[image]

---

#### Now here is the solution of your actual problem

- Override `doStartTag()` that simply returns `EVAL_BODY_INCLUDE` it means this tag contains body and evaluate the body also.
- Override `doAfterBody()` that first check on iterator for next item
- If item is found then set the attribute in the page context and return `EVAL_BODY_AGAIN` to call `doAfterBody()` method again
- If there is no more item then simply return `SKIP_BODY` that means come out of `doAfterBody()` method.

Sample code:

JAVA

```
public class HotelDetails extends BodyTagSupport {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1141701851233089895L;
    private Hotel hotel;
    private ArrayList<Hotel> hotelArray;
    Iterator<Hotel> it;

    public ArrayList<Hotel> getHotelArray() {
        return hotelArray;
    }

    public void setHotelArray(ArrayList<Hotel> hotelArray) {
        this.hotelArray = hotelArray;
        it = hotelArray.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public int doStartTag() throws JspException {
        return EVAL_BODY_INCLUDE;
    }

    @Override
    public int doAfterBody() throws JspException {
        if (it.hasNext()) {
            hotel = it.next();

            pageContext.setAttribute("hotelName", hotel.getName());
            pageContext.setAttribute("hotelDesc", hotel.getDescription());

            return EVAL_BODY_AGAIN;
        } else {
            return SKIP_BODY;
        }

    }
}
```

JSP:

```
<h:HotelDetails hotelArray="<%=hotels%>">
    <c:out value="${hotelName }" /> : <c:out value="${hotelDesc }" />
</h:HotelDetails>
```